# Any reason I shouldn't upgrade to Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Any issues?  Does it replace 3.2?  Appreciate the help/insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as Xcode 4 is a developer preview instead of a supported release, you are taking a big risk if you depend on Xcode for your livelihood. If you are interested only in hobby work, then the only thing you have to loose is a little hair (yes, there are several outstanding issues in preview 3). Once Xcode 4 is released, I think it provides many compelling features and I will happily move my development efforts over to the new version. Unlike Windows/Visual Studio, Xcode releases are not tied to operating system or library versions, and the Xcode team has made it so that versions 3 and 4 play very well together. So you can use either Xcode 3.x or Xcode 4 interchangeably.

Comment: Yes, you can install both. I try to use 4 for all of my development, but not everything works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple: Because it's a Developer **Preview**! :)
(and personally: still crashes a lot on my machine)

And correct me if I'm wrong, but XCode4 still lacks several features.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic features are also still not working as expected. When you write **for** Code Sense will suggest a long list for keywords. But the **for-loop** is still missing from the list. I am sure we all know how to write such a loop but for a beginner it still would be useful as it is in Xcode 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I've found XCode 4 to be stable enough for daily work as of the DP5 release, and Apple is actually encouraging this now.

When (and you will) you run across things that don't work, or XCode crashes, just switch back to XCode 3.2 and work past the issue.  The project file format is compatible so this isn't an issue at all.

Overall, XCode 4 is shaping up to be an awesome tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Core 2 Duo or earlier, DO NOT UPGRADE.  Xcode 4 is a great tool with many wonderful additions, but slower Mac's can't handle it.  You'll often find yourself typing then waiting for the editor to catch up.